# Filter/Join on larger than memory dask dataframe and obtaining results

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I am trying to read multiple parquet files from disk using Dask (approximately 100GB) on a machine of 16GB RAM and perform filters or joins (results still larger than memory)

What is the way to obtain results without raising memory error? (Using `dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute()` loads the whole result into memory which is not desirable)

Comment: This is possible, but the scope is still rather broad... it can help if you provide a more specific use case...

Comment: The problem statement is simple: Read across a large dataset and perform operations such as filter/group-by/joins and generate result, but at any instance only part of the result is shown (paginated view: say, 100 records per page)